# Makefile automatically modifies rule after using the `touch` command, very weird case, anybody has some idea?

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, object-files

I am currently learning c++. I wrote the below Makefile to compile my program:

```
NAME    =   test
CC  =   c++
CFLAGS  =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++98
SRCS    =   test.cpp
OBJS    =   ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}

all:        ${NAME}

%.o:        ${SRCS}
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

${NAME}:    ${OBJS}
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o ${NAME}

clean:      
        rm ${OBJS}

fclean:     clean
        rm ${NAME}

re:     fclean
        all
.PHONY:     all clean fclean re .c.o
```

The Makefile works fine until I use the `touch test.cpp` command to see if it relinks as I intended to.

My Makefile then first recompiles `test.cpp` as it should, then it tries to link `Makefile.o` and output a file `Makefile`.

Below is the output display on my terminal:

```bash
c++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++98 -c test.cpp -o Makefile.o
c++   Makefile.o   -o Makefile
rm Makefile.o
Makefile:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

On top of that, my entire Makefile gets replaced by random strings and characters (not really random but I have no idea where are they from, and a whole bunch of `NUL` characters), here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

I code under WSL2, Windows 11, Ubuntu 20.04, in VSCode.

I would really appreciate some idea, thanks!

I solved the problem by removing the `%.o` rule, so I just compiled with `${CC} ${CFALGS} ${SRCS} -o ${NAME}`.

But I still want to know why compiling to object files first caused the problem

Answer (score 1):

You guessed correctly that the problem is in the `%.o` rule. Look:

```
SRCS    =   test.cpp
...
%.o:        ${SRCS}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

That pattern rule tells Make that the way to build *any* object file is to compile `test.cpp`. And Make always checks to see whether the makefile can be rebuilt, and sure enough, it can be, by compiling `test.cpp` and linking the resulting object file. So you wind up with a makefile which is not a makefile, it is in fact an executable binary file which ought to have been named `test` (which is a bad name, but that's another story).

The fix is easy:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: I see, if I understood well, the `%` character here means compile any .cpp file to any corresponding .o file right?

Comment: @Marcus: Not quite. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules).